# Documentation/Wiki of lsst-sphgeom package?

Tags: python-3.x, geometry

I'm looking for documentations about lsst-sphgeom, which is a Python library for spherical geometry computation in astronomy. The package is pip-installable, and I do find [Pypi website](https://pypi.org/project/lsst-sphgeom/#description) and corresponding [GitHub repository](https://github.com/lsst/sphgeom/tree/main), but cannot find any documents about:

- What do the functions and classes in this library do.
- How to use them.
- etc

Since this library seems to be quite popular, there should be some documents, but I cannot find it for some reason. Does anyone know about it?